# How to use On appear() with SwiftUI on iOS 16

Tags: swiftui, ios16, onappear

I didn't change anything in my code, but since iOS16 the onAppear() part is not working.
selectedParcoursIndexArray.append(0) does not execute,
And app crash on :

```
 get: { self.selectedParcoursIndexArray[num] },
```

Because selectedParcoursIndexArray is empty. And should be filled while VStack appear.

My code :

```
 import SwiftUI

struct DepartsSimultanesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var objCourse : CourseActuelle
    @EnvironmentObject var zindex : Zindex
    @EnvironmentObject var listActuelle : ListActuelle
    @State var selectedParcoursIndexArray : [Int] = [0]
    @State var peutSauvegarder = false
    @State var groupeManager : GroupeManager
    var listeParcoursRestants : [String] = []
    @State private var action: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            HStack{
                ...
            }
        HStack{
          ...
            
        }
        Form{
            Section(header: Text("Coureurs/Choix parcours")){
                ForEach(0 ..< groupeManager.groupeList.count, id:\.self){ num in
                    
                    let detailManager = DetailManager(groupeId: groupeManager.groupeList[num].id, courseId: objCourse.id!)
                    let listeParcoursRestants = listRestants(detailManager: detailManager)
                    let enCourse = detailManager.enCourseList.filter { $0.groupeId == groupeManager.groupeList[num].id }
                    Picker(selection: Binding(
                            get: { self.selectedParcoursIndexArray[num] },
                            set: { (newValue) in
                                self.selectedParcoursIndexArray[num] = newValue
                                peutSauvegarder = true
                            }), label: HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                        Text("\(groupeManager.groupeList[num].nomGroupe)")
                            }.foregroundColor(selectedParcoursIndexArray[num] != 0 ? .orange : Color("ColorDarkLight"))
                    ) {
                        
                        if enCourse.count != 0 {
                          ...
                        }
                    }.navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .disabled(listeParcoursRestants.count == 1 || enCourse.count != 0)

                }
            }
        }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            groupeManager = GroupeManager(courseId: objCourse.id!)
            for _ in (0 ..< groupeManager.groupeList.count) {
                selectedParcoursIndexArray.append(0)

            }
        }
            
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        NavigationLink(destination: CestPartiView().environmentObject(objCourse), tag: 1, selection: $action){}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` is not a for loop, it'll crash if you try to access an array by index inside its closure. `id:\.self` is a mistake, the `id` needs to be a property of the data it cannot be the data itself.

`onAppear` is designed to call an external action not to initialise the data that will be displayed. Move that initialisation somewhere else like to an `@State` struct's init.